# How can i send multipart form data in web service with usertoken

Tags: android, request, http-post, httprequest, multipartform-data

I send multipartform data to webservice with post tokenid, im taking error message in webservice

please signin but i posted my tokenid and its coming fill.

My code below;

```
             conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
             conn.setDoInput(true); 
             conn.setDoOutput(true); 
             conn.setUseCaches(false); 
             conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

             conn.setRequestProperty("token", ""+token2);
             conn.setRequestProperty("type", "album");

             conn.setRequestProperty("platform", "android");
             conn.setRequestProperty("version", ""+versionName);
             conn.setRequestProperty("image", ""+imagepath);
             conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
             conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
             conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
```

Comment: Use android retrofit library by Square. That will make your life easier.

Comment: have u checked my solution

Answer (score 0):

I think u have to work like this

```
public void connectForMultipart() throws Exception {
    con = (HttpURLConnection) ( new URL(url)).openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setDoInput(true);
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
    con.connect();
    os = con.getOutputStream();
}

public void addFormPart(String paramName, String value) throws Exception {
    writeParamData(paramName, value);
}

public void addFilePart(String paramName, String fileName, byte[] data) throws Exception {
    os.write( (delimiter + boundary + "\r\n").getBytes());
    os.write( ("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + paramName +  "\"; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"\r\n"  ).getBytes());
    os.write( ("Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n"  ).getBytes());
    os.write( ("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n"  ).getBytes());
    os.write("\r\n".getBytes());

    os.write(data);

    os.write("\r\n".getBytes());
}   
public void finishMultipart() throws Exception {
    os.write( (delimiter + boundary + delimiter + "\r\n").getBytes());
}
```

I have changed `Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n"` to `Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n` and it worked :)